# need help understanding getRequest() Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, forms

I'm doing this tutorial:
http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/Zend-Framework-Database-Creating-Input-Form-P494.html

We are building a simple input form using POST and submitting it to a mySQL database.  All is working fine.  I'm just trying to get my head around the getRequest() function.

In the controller, we have this:

```
public function registerAction()
 {
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    $this->view->assign('action',"process");
    $this->view->assign('title','Member Registration');
    $this->view->assign('label_fname','First Name');
    $this->view->assign('label_lname','Last Name'); 
    $this->view->assign('label_uname','User Name'); 
    $this->view->assign('label_pass','Password');
    $this->view->assign('label_submit','Register');     
    $this->view->assign('description','Please enter this form completely:');        
}
```

and then in view:

```
 <form name="register" method="post" action="<?php echo $this->escape($this->action)?>">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $this->escape($this->label_fname)?></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="first_name"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $this->escape($this->label_lname)?></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="last_name"></td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $this->escape($this->label_uname)?></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="user_name"></td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $this->escape($this->label_pass)?></td>
      <td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
    </tr>   
  </table>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="<?php echo $this->escape($this->label_submit);?>">
  </form>
```

So what I don't understand is why do we need a getRequest() if I already have the method="post" and the action set?  If I comment it out, the script doesn'twork.  I see it's needed, but I don't understand why-especially since the $request variable doesn't seem to be used?

Comment: Before long you should look into the Zend_Db_Table_Abstract class.  It has methods for handling SQL statements so you don't have to roll your own.  The code in the tutorial is ripe for an SQL-injection attack.

Comment: @peter-I believe that is the next tutorial there-he starts looking at other ways to feed the Db.

Comment: Cool, You'll probably like Zend_Form as well, it makes populating forms with values a snap.

Comment: I don't like to be negative about other peoples' work but that tutorial is very poor. I'd recommend a read through of http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/ paying particular attention to the sections where forms are used.

Comment: @david thanks for your comment.  I disagree.  This tutorial has been great in explaining basics very simply-This tutorial isn't even on forms, it's about inputting data to the database.  That is one of the things I REALLY like about this tutorial is he takes one very basic concept and shows you how to do it, and then moves on to address the next issue (for example the very next tutorial shows how to replace the Db connection with Zend_Db_Table_Abstract).  I feel strongly that Zend Framework tutorials are very very lacking for complete newbies (like myself) and try to do too much too fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you have provided, $request doesn't appear to be used at all. I don't see why commenting it out would break.

What happens, exactly, when you comment it out?

The getRequest() function is for getting the Request object, which gives you parameters and such (i.e. controller, action, etc);

**EDIT:**

I had a look at the tutorial, and it has this:

```
12   
13    $sql = "INSERT INTO `user`
14            (`first_name` , `last_name` ,`user_name` ,`password`)
15            VALUES
16            ('".$request->getParam('first_name')."', '".$request->getParam('last_name')."', '".$request->getParam('user_name')."', MD5('".$request->getParam('password')."'))";
17    $DB->query($sql);
```

You'll note that it uses the $request variable to get the Parameters: 
'first_name', 'last_name', 'user_name', 'password'

And saves them into the DB.

Comment: Commenting it out, I get the "An Error Occurred Application Error" message.  uncomment it and it works.

Comment: @Valorin-the SQL code you just added is in a different method and view, and also contains it's own getRequest with $request.

Comment: aw-jeez-I was making a stupid mistake-I wasn't clearing the fields when I was testing the commenting/uncommenting, and so it was trying to put duplicate content into the Db and getting an error.  When I put in new content, I can comment that line out and things still work.  Cool-one less confusing thing to deal with!